# Custom TableCellRenderer negative numbers align to right

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have `Jtable` with custom cells' renderer, which should align its content to right:

```
public class BriefViewCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
        int row, int column) {

      setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
      setText("-200");
   }
}
```

JTable looks nice, except negative numbers. The minus sign apears behind the actual number.
[image: A row from the table]

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: please my three questions 1. if negative sing must be at the end, 2. why by using Components Orientation, 3. why the String value

Comment: never use the Renderer to change state of value stored in model, is about formatting, highligting, alingment

Comment: No, negative sign should be in front of the number and the sign and the number should be on the right side of JTextArea.